# Can you hollow out the inside of an Alarm spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

After reading [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112756/does-no-larger-than-imply-shapability), I thought up a scenario that I wasn't sure if it was answered inside there. If you have a normal use of the [Alarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) spell filling up a 20-foot cube, could you leave a space the size of a 10-foot cube on the ground in the middle to be unaffected by the spell? A reason you might want to do this is if you have a creature captured and bound, and you want to be alerted if he leaves his space. You would cast the Alarm spell on the area around him (within the 20-foot cube), leaving the square the he occupies out, otherwise you would be constantly alerted, as the spell states (emphasis mine):

> Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you **whenever a Tiny or larger creature touches or enters** the warded area.

Is this hollowing out of the Alarm spell possible?

Comment: What part of this is not covered by the linked question?

Comment: I believe that answer addresses the interpretation of having an entire volume of a 20-ft cube to make a ring out of, but that's going past the boundaries of a 20-ft cube and not what I'm asking. For example, If I say there's an area for fans to sit in a hockey stadium, the area would fit in the building but wouldn't take up the entire building, right? There would be the rink in the middle, where fans can't sit. I'm applying that logic to the Alarm spell, where the fans area (which the spell affects) is within a 20-ft cube, but the rink area (a 10-ft cube in the middle) is not affected by it.

Comment: I suggest reading the second answer there, furthermore, the question does actually ask whether it means the area you create must have less volume or just actually fit *inside* the cube. "Does no larger than a 20 foot cube mean no measurement can be larger than 20 feet? Or does it mean the area or volume cannot exceed that of a 20 foot cube?"

Comment: Ah, I read a little closer to the first part of that answer this time. So the answer to my question would be yes, to my understanding. Sorry for the duplicate question in that case, and even having a link to it within my question. I feel like a fool.

Comment: Nah you're good. I definitely see how the first answer, I don't know, takes its time? There's definitely a few things being asked at once so it's a reasonable mistake. Plus now we've got another duplicate source for the search results, so that's good too. You've also got some upvotes so enjoy that rep as well